# Need to change all orders to complete

Tags: orders, order-status

We need to change all our orders to complete (600k)

Is there an easy script to accomplish this?

I am not sure if this is to safe?

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'complete';  
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state = 'complete', status = 'complete';
```

Comment: Just to add - This seems to have worked, I am testing

Answer (score 1):

Change order state by cron job

This is the working program-

```
 const MINUTES_DELAY = 15; //Orders younger than this are not changed
  const OUT_FILE = '/home/vinayak/cron.txt';

  public function run() {
    $old_time = time() - (self::MINUTES_DELAY*60);

    $out = "-------------------------------------------\n";
    $out .= date('d.m.y h:i:s A')."\n";

    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
      ->addFieldToFilter('cod_fee', array('null' => true))
      ;

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
      if (strtotime($order->getCreatedAt()) < $old_time)  {
        try{
          $id = $order->getIncrementId();

          Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->loadByIncrementId($id)
            ->setState('pending_payment', true)
            ->save();

          $out .= $id."\n";
        } catch (Exception $e)  {
          $out .= "Caught exception : ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
        }
      }
    }
    file_put_contents(self::OUT_FILE, $out, FILE_APPEND);
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's usually safer to use Magento's API rather than to modify the database directly. Updating via the API triggers any other Magento events associated with the actions, which you may not be aware of.

In your case, you could write a separate php script similar to:

```
require_once([path to magento]/Mage.php);

// Start Magento
$app = Mage::app();

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
  $old_state = $order->getState();

  $order->setState('complete');
  $order->setStatus('complete');
  $order->save();

  $new_state = $order->getState();
  echo "Modified order $order->getId(): Old state: $old_state. New state: $new_state\n";
}
```

And then run it on the command line:

```
php update_orders.php
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file order.php in the root folder of magento and then copy the below code then run this file.

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
$app = Mage::app("default");

$allOrders=Mage::getModel("sales/order");
$orders = $salesModel->getCollection();
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    $order->setStatus('complete');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of make an Order collection  filter by  non cancel and  non complete,because you cannot

save any order if it complete  or cancel.

Second , order all items is invoice or not if not make invoice.

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
if(!$order->canInvoice())
{
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($invoice)
->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
}
```

More detail about Programmatically create invoice of a order in magento -  at: http://www.amitbera.com/programmatically-create-invoice-of-a-new-order-in-magento/

Third , order all items is shipment or not if not make shipment.

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
if( $shipment ) {
     $shipment->register();
     $order->setIsInProcess(true);

     $transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                ->addObject($shipment)
                                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                                ->save();
}
```

after 
that

```
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->save();
```

FUll code

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'status',
        'nin'        => array('complete','cancel'),
        )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ;
foreach ($orders as $eachorder) {

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eachorder->getId());
if(!$order->canInvoice())
{
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($invoice)
->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
}


$shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
if( $shipment ) {
     $shipment->register();
     $order->setIsInProcess(true);

     $transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                ->addObject($shipment)
                                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                                ->save();
}


$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->save();



}
```